# Is it a bad idea for multiple ColdFusion applications to use the same client variable store?

Tags: coldfusion

We have two ColdFusion applications that share a common database.  There are three instances of each application.  (One instance of each application runs on each of three servers.)

I can see that the three instances of a given application should share a client variable store.  (Load-balancing can cause a single user session to bounce between the three instances.)  My question is:  Is there any danger to having all instances of *both* applications share the same data store?  Or should only one application be pointing at a given data store?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the same client data store.  The CDATA table has an 'app' column that stores the coldfusion application name.  That column will keep your data unique to each application.

Answer (score 2):

I'm working at an enterprise level ColdFusion shop with multiple CF applications running on the same server that are all pointed at the same client variable store. The only concern within the organization is how the client variable store affects regular backups, and that falls under the data team's purview. We don't have any problems with the different apps actually using the same client variable storage.

Answer (score 1):

Related, from the [ColdFusion documentation](http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=sharedVars_08.html):

> Some browsers allow only 20 cookies to
>   be set from a particular host.
>   ColdFusion uses two of these cookies
>   for the CFID and CFToken identifiers,
>   and also creates a cookie named
>   cfglobals to hold global data about
>   the client, such as HitCount,
>   TimeCreated, and LastVisit. This
>   limits you to 17 unique applications
>   per client-host pair.

I guess this deals more with how many applications you actually run rather than whether you have them all share the same client data store, but it does suggest that there may be some kind of hard limit on the total number of apps you can run at once, although I'd recommend splitting across hosts (or just using a different domain name) if you're planning on more than 16 apps!

As Eric stated above, running multiple apps off of one datasource is fine. What I would warn you is that these databases can fill up fast if you're not careful to block spiders and search engines from using them. Because CF creates client variables on each request for a new session, a search engine will get a new one every time because it never sends its old credentials/cookies so CF thinks it's a new user who needs a new client variable set. Also, be absolutely certain to check "Disable global client variable updates" in CF admin. This will save you a lot of unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score -1):

I would think that multiple applications sharing the same data store would open up the possibility of users from one application having access to the other applications.  While it may not be likely, the possibility *could* exist.  (I don't have any facts to back that up, it just seems like a logical conclusion).

The question is, are you comfortable with that possibility, or do you have to absolutely make sure each application is secure?

Comment: Really?  I express and opinion and admit that I have no facts to back it up, and I get a down vote?  Holy crap people!